# How is the sum of two Lebesgue integrable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm practicing for the final exam in real-analysis and I am at the chapter Measure Theory and Integration. I found this exercise, but I don't know how to solve it...Could you please help me?
Let $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f, g : X → \mathbb{R}$. Determine if the following implications hold in general:
(i) both functions $f$ and $g$ are integrable $⇒ f + g$ is integrable;
(ii) $f + g$ is integrable $⇒$ at least one of the functions $f$ or $g$ is integrable;

Comment: That's four questions!

Comment: That's now two questions! (i) is standard theory, and (ii) is obviously false.

Comment: I need proofs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you say integrable you mean that the integral of the function is finite.

I belive that for the item $(i)$ you can use the property that the integral is additive and you will get your answer.

For $(ii)$ I belive it is false because you can consider $f=-x$ and $g=x$ and you get that $f+g=0$.

Comment: So, for $(ii)$, $f+g$ is constant so it is integrable, but $-x$ and $x$ are not integrable?

Comment: You have the the integral of $f+g$ is $0$, it is not because it is constant ,  while the integral of $f$ and $g$ are $\infty$ and $-\infty$, again I might be using a different definition of integrable than you , what is your definition ?

Comment: It may look a stupid question, but why the integral of $f$ and $g$ are $\infty$?

Comment: When you are doing the integral you are basically calculating the measure of the set that is under between the graph of the function and $x=0$ and this will be $\infty$ , you can see that for any $n$ you have a $\sigma-$elementar set in there with measure $n^2/2$.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you!